# How do I set maven to look in central before my own repository

Tags: maven, repository

As stated, how do I search central *first* followed by my own. I cant find any documentation stating how to, or indeed that is is even possible.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by: `by my own`? Are you talking about your local cache? Or are you talking about a repository manager ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "my own repository" means "my repository manager", you can do so by declaring Maven Central repository first in your `<repositories>` section :

```
<repositories>
    <!-- first, Maven Central -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- then, your own repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>my-repository</id>
        <name>my-repository</name>
        <url>https://my.repository.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

To resolve dependencies with this configuration, Maven will first look in your cache (`~/.m2/repository`), then in Maven Central, and finally in your own repository.